# How to Draw Polygon Array From JSON on Google Maps V3

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3

I have a JSON string which contains polygon array. Can you please let me know how I can update following code to loop and parse the polygons from this WebAPI (JSON). You can find the coordinates of the polygon to "Perimeter" - http://track.asiacom.co.th/fmswebapi/api/zoneinfo

Here are my codes

```
var url = 'http://track.asiacom.co.th/fmswebapi/api/zoneinfo';

$.getJSON(url, function (zones) {


    for (var i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {

        var zone = zones[i];
        var name = zone.Name;
        var type = zone.Type;
        var perimeter = zone.Perimeter;
        var company = zone.Company;
        var color = zone.Color;


        var coords = perimeter.split(",");


        pathCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1])));


        // Construct the polygon.
        polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            path: pathCoordinates,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map
        });


        polygon.setMap(map);




        // Add a listener for the click event.
        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', showArrays);

        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



        // Click Zones
        google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', (function (polygon, i) {

            return function () {

                map.panTo(this.position);

            }

        })(polygon, i));

    }

    return zones;

}

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really necessary that you use with json string or just an example? if not an example your application will fail when another patron comes on the perimeter ... anyway I draw, (you got one Polygono only has 2 points).

Edit: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gujocilela/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
$(function () {
initialize();
});
    var url = 'http://track.asiacom.co.th/fmswebapi/api/zoneinfo';
    var pathCoordinates = [];
    var map;

  function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.473727562827564, 180.55709464999995),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true
    });
  }




$.getJSON(url, function (zones) {
console.log(zones);

for (var i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {

    var zone = zones[i];
    var name = zone.Name;
    var type = zone.Type;
    var perimeter = zone.Perimeter;
    var company = zone.Company;
    var color = zone.Color;


    var coords = perimeter.split(" ");
    var recoords;
    for (var k = 0; k < coords.length; k++) {
          recoords = coords[k].split(",");
          pathCoordinates.push(new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(recoords[0]), parseFloat(recoords[1])));
    };



    // Construct the polygon.
    polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: pathCoordinates,
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        Company: company,
        Name: name,
        map: map
    });

    pathCoordinates = [];
}

    polygon.setMap(map);

});
```

If you are not using this mode to get the lat / lng and using c # or java look at this thread [Return object(markers,polygon,polyline) to javascript from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134831/displaying-multiple-markers-on-google-maps-with-latitude-and-longitude-values-re/30136954#30136954)

Sorry for my English ;)

Comment: Yes, it's necessary that I'm using JSON. Thank you for solving this problem.